How to prove odd Bernoulli numbers are 0
I went through some of the proofs of the fact that odd Bernoulli numbers that is not one is $0$. I see that they use some extended definitions of Bernoulli numbers, I am wondering if there is a simpler proof just using the basic recursive definitions or less.
This is my proof. Is it valid?
$$\forall s \in \mathbb{N} s \neq 1\ \text{and}\ s\equiv1\ \left(mod\ 2\right)\ B_s=0$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^s &= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(k^s+\left(n-k\right)^s\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\ \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \times \left(\sum_{p=0}^{s-1}{k^p\times\left(n-k\right)^{\left(s-1-p\right)}\times\left(-1\right)^p}\right)} \\
&=\frac{n}{2}\ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{p=0}^{s-1}{\left(-1\right)^pk^p\times\sum_{g=0}^{s-1-p}{n^g\times\left(-k\right)^{s-1-p-g}}}
\end{align*}
Take out the lowest power of $n$ to study
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{p=0}^{s-1}{\left(-1\right)^pk^p\times n^0\times\left(-k\right)^{s-1-p}} &=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{p=0}^{s-1}{\left(-1\right)^{p+1}\times k^{s-1}} \sum_{p=0}^{s-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{p+1}\times k^{s-1}}\\
&=\ \sum_{p=0}^{s-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{p+1}\times\frac{B_{s-1}\left(n\right)}{s}} 
\end{align*}
Since $B_{s-1}\left(n\right)$ has no constant term, we know that the power of $\frac{n}{2} \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{p=0}^{s-1}{\left(-1\right)^pk^p\times\sum_{g=0}^{s-1-p}{n^g\times\left(-k\right)^{s-1-p-g}}}$ is at least 2 meaning that $A_1^s=B_s=0$

Please reformat your equations using the align* environment.

Math mode isn't intended for italicizing text; as you can see here, it yields the wrong spacing for that. Usually text is italicized by enclosing it in asterisks. If you want to italicize text within math mode, you can use \mathit{...}. In the present case, there doesn't seem to be a need to italicize the text; in that case you can use \text{...} to include roman text in math mode.
